# How to overwrite a datetime.now() object

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a `get_date` function which I want to use to build higher-level functions (for example, `get_payment_date` given below). This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_date(year=None, month=None, day=None):
    '''Returns now, with the given parts overwritten'''
    dt = datetime.now()
    if not year  is None : dt.year  = year
    if not month is None : dt.month = month
    if not day   is None : dt.day   = day
    return dt

def get_payment_date():
    return get_date(day=15)

print get_payment_date()
```

But if fails:

```
AttributeError: attribute 'day' of 'datetime.date' objects is not writable
```

I get it. How can I solve this? How can I "overwrite" only some parts of `now`?

Comment: `get_date(month=15)` what does this mean? That it is 15 months from now?

Comment: Oooops, bad example. Let me correct it.

Comment: What are you looking for? there is no way to over write datetime, however you could try to generate a new list of (year, month, day) and then generate the new datetime

Comment: I get that I can not modify a datetime object. How can I create the datetime object with the same values as `now` would return, but with *some* parts fixed by me?

Comment: @gonvaled Yes, that you can.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`datetime.datetime` and `datetime.date` objects are immutable.

You can do `dt = dt.replace(year = year)` to get a new datetime object based on an old one.

You don't necessarily want to do that three times, but something like this might suit you:

```
def get_date(**kwargs):
    '''Returns now, with the given parts overwritten'''
    dt = datetime.now()
    # optionally, depending on intended use of this function
    kwargs = { k : v for k,v in kwargs.items() if v is not None }
    return dt.replace(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! That is whay I was looking for. I missed it in the docs :(

Answer (score 1):

This is what I wanted (thanks to Steve Jessop):

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_date(year=None, month=None, day=None):
    '''Returns now, with the given parts overwritten'''
    dt = datetime.now()
    kwargs = {}
    if year  : kwargs['year']  = year
    if month : kwargs['month'] = month
    if day   : kwargs['day'] = day
    if kwargs : return dt.replace(**kwargs)
    else      : return dt

def get_payment_date():
    return get_date(day=15)

print get_payment_date()
```

Notice that I need to build a `kwargs` since `dt.replace` does not accept `None` as value for `year / month / day`. Also, I removed `is not None` check, since a 0 value means also no replacement.

Comment: FYI, `datetime.datetime.replace()` already returns the identical object if `kwargs` is empty, so you don't need to do that test if you don't want.

Comment: @SteveJessop: ah! you mean that last check? But I guess the check is less overhead than calling replace, even if it is doing nothing?

Comment: it's probably a tiny bit less effort if it does nothing, and is a tiny bit more effort if it calls `replace` (because `replace` does the same check again). I was thinking about the amount of code, though, rather than performance.